# Re-enable automatic pinning to start screen

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

Just got a new laptop with Windows 8 (unfortunately) and I notice that downloaded apps/programs aren't automatically added to the Start Screen.

From [here](http://mashable.com/2013/05/30/windows-8-1-features/) it seems that this was a "feature" added in 8.1 to reduce clutter in the start screen.

However, I personally would like to enable this, as the apps I'm currently downloading are those I use frequently.

Anyone know if it's possible to re-enable this feature? Thanks.

Comment: This option cannot be re-enabled.

Comment: it can be done via GPO. Use a translator to read this: http://www.borncity.com/blog/2014/02/19/windows-8-1-kacheln-bei-app-installation-erzwingenteil-1/ http://www.borncity.com/blog/2014/02/20/windows-8-1-kacheln-bei-app-installation-erzwingenteil-2